# While importing daypilot lite getting the error :Type 'typeof DayPilot' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any> | ModuleWithProviders<{}>

Tags: angular, daypilot

i installed daypilot-lite-angular library but when i tried to import it in my app.module
it threw me an error like this:

`"Type 'typeof DayPilot' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any> | ModuleWithProviders<{}>'"`

while importing in the app.module:

```
import { DayPilot } from "@daypilot/daypilot-lite-angular";
```

i tried to enter the "DayPilot " in the import line or the declaration but both gives the same error.
anybody knows what causes that?